# On uniquely determining a bounded surface in 3D space when the planar projections are given

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, surfaces, projection, planar-graphs

Let $f(x,y,z)=0$ is a bounded closed surface defined in $D^3$ Where $D$ is a finite closed interval included in real number set. The planar projections of the surface are given:

1. On $z=0$ plane the Projection is given.
2. On $y=0$ the Projection is given.
3. On $x=0$ the  Projection is given.

From the above mentioned planar projections  can we uniquely determine the original surface?

Comment: It must depend on the function, a function for which the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ consisted of concentric spheres would have all the same projections as one whose surface was only the largest sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D=[-1,1]$ and consider the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ where
$$
f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)(x^2+y^2+z^2-r^2)
$$
for some fixed $r\in (0,1)$.

Then the projections are independent of the choice of $r$.

To address your comment, to show an example where the surface is connected and bounds a connected region, we can modify the above example as follows . . .

Let $D=[-1,1]$ and consider the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ where
$$
f(x,y,z)
=
\Bigl(z-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\Bigr)
\Bigl(z-a\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\Bigr)
$$
for some fixed $a\in (0,1)$.

Then the projections are independent of the choice of $a$, and the region bounded by the surface is connected.

Comment: How about if we ask the solid enclosed by the surface is connected?

Comment: @Aria: I've edited in an example for which the surface bounds a connected region.

Comment: Smart example you made thanks

Comment: how about a case that the unit normal of the surface varies smoothly

Comment: @Aria: Your turn. First sketch it as a smooth join of two smooth surfaces, one of which doesn't affect the projections, and then define the pieces algebraically to match the sketch.